# Vague warning message when extracting tiff data

Tags: r, extract

I've unpacked the following libraries

```
library(BIOMASS)
library(readr)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(ncdf4) 
library(tidyverse)
```

I've succesfully stacked a tiff file

`s1 <- stack('XXX.tif')`

I now want to extract this using 
`s1_e <- extract(s1,pspcoord,method='bilinear')`

I get the following warning message when running previous line

> In proj4string(x) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output

NOTE: Earlier in the code i had run the following line concerning proj4string 
`plotcoord <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(AGCplot[,3:4], AGCplot[,1:2],proj4string=CRS('+proj=longlat'))` 
`pspcoord<-spTransform(plotcoord, CRS('+proj=utm +zone=21'))`

Q: What does this warning message mean?